# I want to know how to implement click() in Python

Tags: python

I want to know how to implement click() in Python.

I know I can click() the element I found with "selenium".
By the way, is there a way to click() an element even in the combination of "requests" + "beautifulsoup"?

Comment: Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it. - see [What topics can I ask about here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) . As you're new, please take the [tour] and read [ask] too, to understand how to get the best out of Stackoverflow.